# Maximum Call Stack Size Exceeded Error in Express App with Body Parser

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, body-parser

I'm only occasionally getting this error and I don't really have any steps to duplicate it in the app other than to try and do as many things as possible to generate as much traffic in the app as possible. Still unsure if this is an issue with some middleware or something else entirely. I currently use body-parser in the app which is setup per their instructions.

If I use Postman, I get this error back when I make a call to *OPTIONS /server_url*. When this error triggers, it will always generate this error for all network requests to OPTIONS, POST and DELETE - which need to be done for CORS related stuff. GET and PUT requests still seem to work no problem for whatever reason.

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
   at proxy (../node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:643:8)
   at next (../node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:206:14)
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (../node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:97:5)
   at ../node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:277:22
   at param (../node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:349:14)
   at param (../node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:365:14)
   at Function.process_params (../node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:410:3)
   at next (../node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
   at next (../node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:121:14)
   at next (../node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:125:14)
   at next (../node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:125:14)
   at next (../node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:125:14)
   at next (../node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:125:14)
   at next (../node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:125:14)
   at next (../node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:125:14)
   at next (../node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:125:14)
```

I'm quite lost on where to even begin on this one after taking a number of attempts at figuring it out. If I reboot my app, it'll start working properly again - until I do enough in the app and it triggers this error again. Also, the memory utilization in the app is normal from what I can see and the server has plenty of memory still available.

Comment: Can you show the code for a route that this is happening to?

Comment: Once it starts, this will happen even if it's a call to just OPTIONS /widget which normally returns GET, HEAD, PUT - which isn't even running code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was related to a piece of middleware that was calling next() and doing a lot of operations afterwards. Wrapping the next in process.nextTick() resolved the call stack issue for now. I should note, it took using node-inspector to locate the issue

Answer (score 1):

I solve my problem by this.

```
var bodyparser = require('body-parser');
```

instead of `app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));`
write this

```
var urlencodedParser = bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: false });
```

Answer (score 0):

It probably looks like a memory leak somewhere or some infinite loop somewhere or the request not finishing (which may not be true as the request comes with a default timeout of 1000s).

Comment: This is the bizarre thing, I'm using pm2, and when this is happening the memory usage goes to 98MB from 80-90MB. Not sure if that indicates a memory leak or not.

I also have almost 80% code coverage with unit tests as well, and don't encounter this issue anywhere but when I push it into production environment.

Comment: circular dependencies also sometimes could trigger such issues

Comment: I removed one piece of middleware that I have in place, and now the error happens faster and will happen on an OPTIONS call, yet a GET will still work. Going to try node-inspector next to see if that shows me anything useful. I should say, the memory of the application now is spiking over 200MB. Has to be a memory leak.